# GreenDao Sort dataset not query result

Tags: java, android, query-builder, greendao

I'm using GreenDao's QueryBuilder to query for items i need in my list.

I have an extremely large dataset of categories with names
eg (Tools, Engines, Pliers, Bricks)

I need to use offset and limit to collect 250 items at a time as getting the entire list causes the curser to request too much memory and throw OOM

But the problem i face is i need the dataset itself to be sorted, not the results of my query (The first 250 items in the dataset may be from G to X, but 3 items down the line might be an item with the name "Bricks".

How would i sort the dataset that i have before performing the Query request?.

Comment: You just can't. And why would you want to? The data stored in the DB is essentially unsorted. The sorting is done by assigning one or more indices on the table and is only important when fetching the data (querying).

Comment: Thats a shame, because i want to display a list of the categories, from A to Z in a listview, it doesn't help to load items with name G to X before i load items A to G which is my issue

Comment: It would help if you could post the scheme of your data. But I'm having difficulty understanding your need. You can easily get items sorted from A to Z by adding `ORDER BY name ASC` to your query. You can even have multiple sort criteria. Somthing like `ORDER BY name ASC, category DESC`.

Comment: I have the Query to grab 250 Category items at a time, (using offset and limit)
 The ORDER BY name ASC will sort the results of the Query, not the dataset its grabbing the items from,
I need the dataset sorted, not the query results

Comment: Again I ask why do you want to sort the dataset? You're not doing anything with it.

Comment: i'm displaying the names in a listview that is alphabetized

Comment: You're displaying the query result. Not the raw data in the Database.

Comment: yes. but i want the query to return results in an alphabetized order from the dataset,

okay, say i have this dataset (Danny, Sam, Aaron, Betty, Simon),
due to my restrictions, i can only get 2 names at a time, if i query now i will get (Danny, Sam), and ordering then ASC i'll get (Danny, Sam), i want to get (Aaron, Betty) in my query, not (Danny, Sam), so i need to reorder the dataset to (Aaron, Betty, Danny, Sam, Simon) before doing my query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188574/discussion-between-hamed-momeni-and-brandon).